# VBA in Powerpoint : Text Box Value

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to compare the value of 2 text boxes in powerpoint, and highlight the one with the highest numerical value.

Here's my code :

```
If ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Rectangle 84").TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Value >= ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Rectangle 95").TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Value Then XXXX
```

Unfortunately if Rectangle 84 has a value of "11" and Rectangle 95 a value of 6, then currently the 6 is highlighted.
Is there any way to convert the text to a numerical value so I get the right result please?

Thanks
James

Comment: `CInt` or `Cdbl` can help you convert text to numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the values to numbers first, for example using `CLng` (convert to long) or `CDbl` (convert to double) if you expect non-integers.

```
If CDbl(ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Rectangle 84").TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Value) >= CDbl(ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Rectangle 95").TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Value) Then XXXX
```

The string `"11"` is "smaller" than `"6"` because they get sorted alphabetically.

You could also check if the text is valid using `IsNumeric` before converting to prevent type mismatches